# WinBioEnumDatabases returns incorrect count of values

Tags: windows, biometrics

I have a wrapper around the [WinBioEnumDatabases](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd401623.aspx) function in the [WBF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd401507.aspx); however it's returning three of the **same** databases (as evidenced by the fact that they have the same ID and path). There's only one physical file in the location pointed to by the path.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like there's going to be no answers so I've implemented a workaround where I check the previous database's ID and path. If they're both equal then I don't add them in the UI. Willing to accept any other answer though...